# Simple way to do mapping of group of sequential list elements

Tags: list, mapping, raku, sequential

Normal mapping applies a function to a list element and produces an element of the resultant list. E.g., if list is `(1, 2, 3,)` and maps the square function, you get a new list `(1, 4, 9,)`.

Is there a way to map a group of sequential elements of a list? For instance, if the list is `<8 2 7 2 6 9 4 9 6 1>` and I want to calculate the sum of every 2 elements of the list to make `<10 9 9 8 15 13 13 15 7>`?

I can certainly write a routine to traverse the list. But I am looking for an easier way, like the reduction operator or like the gather/take.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`.rotor`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/rotor) method to partition a list into overlapping sublists:

```perl6
say <8 2 7 2 6 9 4 9 6 1>.rotor(2 => -1);

# Output:
# ((8 2) (2 7) (7 2) (2 6) (6 9) (9 4) (4 9) (9 6) (6 1))
```

The `2 => -1` is a `Pair` argument which signifies to the method that it should generate the sublists by going "two forward, one back" at each step.

Then you can simply use `.map` to apply your operation (e.g. sum) to each sublist:

```perl6
say <8 2 7 2 6 9 4 9 6 1>.rotor(2 => -1).map(*.sum);

# Output:
# (10 9 9 8 15 13 13 15 7)
```

Comment: Thanks smls !! This is great !! Makes me love perl6 even more !!

Answer (score 6):

The functional programming way to do this is to reference the list twice, offset one version by an element, and zip them together. This gives you all the tuples of subsequent elements.

```
my @l := <a b c d e f>;
say @l Z @l[1..*]; # output: ((a b) (b c) (c d) (d e) (e f))
```

If you don't want to create a temporary variable to hold the list, use `given` (and use `do given` if you need the statement to return a value):

```
given <8 2 7 2 6 9 4 9 6 1> {
  say ($_ Z $_[1..*]).map: -> [$a, $b] { $a+$b };
}
```

If you're using a function that takes two parameters, you may want to flatten the list after zipping and let `map` take two elements at a time:

```
given <8 2 7 2 6 9 4 9 6 1> {
  say ($_ Z $_[1..*]).flat.map(&infix:<+>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, piojo !! Your answer really helped !! Is there a reason you used @[$a,$b] instead of [$a,$b] or ($a,$b)? They all give the same results. Thanks again!

Comment: @smls Thanks, I changed it.

Comment: @lisprogtor I didn't realize you could destructure without a variable name or sigil. Thanks for letting me know. I updated the example.

Comment: why not use `Z+` to perform the addition?

Comment: @Christoph I don't think addition is the OP's real goal. It sounds like a placeholder to take the place of a more significant operation.